# How to create 0..1 to many relationship in octobercms?

Tags: database, octobercms

I have a table category it has a self relation to have belongs_to simply to be able to create subcategories and assign them to previously created categories and now i need to be able to either assign the new category to another (super) category or to assign it to none.

my model is :

```
    public $belongsTo = [
    'category' => ['plugin\pdf\models\Category']
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is found in the [documents](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-relation) under backend -> forms. Look for the `relation` under widget fields. The option you is called `emptyOption` and it will be added in your `fields.yaml` file.

You would add the `emptyOption` like so to model's fields.yaml.

```
    field:
        label: Field Label
        nameFrom: name
        descriptionFrom: description
        span: auto
        type: relation
        emptyOption: None
```